# Throws an error when installing the n package in node

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-install, install.packages

When installing n it throws an error and without the installation of n how would I update my node.
Here is the error:

```
`suman@Suman MINGW64 ~
$ npm install -g n
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@9.1.0: wanted {"os":"!win32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\suman\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-06T12_42_44_874Z-debug-0.log`
```

I was trying to install n package so by which I can update my node using my terminal but when installing it throws an error.

Comment: `n` does not support Windows.

Answer (score 1):

See [Supported Platforms](https://github.com/tj/n#supported-platforms)

> `n` is supported on macOS, Linux, including with Windows Subsystem for Linux, and various other unix-like systems.

For Windows OS, you can use [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

I recommend [Install Linux on Windows with WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install), so that you can use `n`